# Reconnect SqlDataAdapter

Tags: sqldataadapter

I have this code

```
    DataTable dt= new DataTable();
    SqlDataAdapter da;


    private void LoadData()
        {
           using (SqlConnection cnn = new   SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["cnn"].ConnectionString))
            {


            da = new SqlDataAdapter("Select * from table",cnn);                
            da.Fill(dt);

            }

        }
```

The connection will be closed after, right?
If i want to update the DataTable, how can i reconnect da to cnn?

Comment: What happens When you set the UpdateCommnd? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldataadapter.updatecommand(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: When you say update do you mean just do the select again from new entries in the table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the using statement will call Dispose on the SqlConnection. See [using Statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx).

To reconnect in this fashion you'd need another using statement to do your update or update within the original using statement.

Comment: Thanks. Should I instantiate a new SqlDataAdapter, so that i can put the connection in the constructor?

Comment: You should be able to just set the command on the SqlDataAdapter object and reuse it.

Answer (score 0):

The Fill method retrieves rows from the data source using the SELECT statement specified by an associated SelectCommand property. The connection object associated with the SELECT statement must be valid, but it does not need to be open. If the connection is closed before Fill is called, it is opened to retrieve data, then closed. If the connection is open before Fill is called, it remains open.

Source:[See this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/377a8x4t.aspx)